# Centralizers of Matrices

Tags: matrices

let $A$ be a complex matrix. Denote by $J(A)$ the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$. Let $C[J(A)]$ be the centralizer of $J(A)$ in $M_n(\mathbb C)$. Can we construct a real matrix $B$, that is, $B$ has only real entries,  verifying the equality $C[J(A)]=C(B)$, in $M_n(\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$J(A)$ can be written as $S+N$, where $S$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent (and has only entries $0$ and $1$). Moreover, *$S$ and $N$ are polynomials in $J(A)$*.

It follows that $C$ centralizes $J(A)$ if and only if it centralizes $S$ and $N$.

The recipe for $B$ is now clear, $B = T+N$, where $T$ is obtained from $S$ by replacing the distinct eigenvalues with distinct real numbers.

This is because $S$ and $T$ have the same centralizer, which consists of block diagonal matrices, with arbitrary blocks on each eigenspace.

Comment: +1 Nice argument. By the way, should $B$ be $T+kN (k\in\mathbb{C})$ instead of $T+N$?

Comment: @user1551, why do that? Moreover, $B$ must be real.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant $k\in\mathbb{R}$. You see, if $C$ centralizes $S$ and $N$, it also centralizes $kN$ for every real $k$.